# how do you use python regular expressions when there isn't always more than one match?

Tags: python, regex

I have some text I would like to find between brackets for example, I would like to extract the 70 from "View All (70) Network"

I've kindly been shown by stack overflow users to use the pyrex website to practice buildig regular expressions and with their guidance I have been able to successfully do so.

My problem comes when using the GROUP function of the RegEx.

I believe **GROUP** is used to get the first or second occurrence of the string, and in most cases there is more than one,

it may Say " View All (6)" and "View All (70) so .group[1] would return the 70. but how do I tell it if there is only one instance that I still need it to get the value?

**The error I get is:**

```
NoneType: object has no attribute group
```

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this? I could stop using regular expressions but they save time coding all sorts of other text manipulation logic.

Answer (score 0):

The group() is based on the identifying capture groups you've defined. For example:

```
import re

searchText = "(ONE) TWO THREE"
result = re.search("(ONE)", searchText).group(1)
print("match:", result)
```

output: `('match:', 'ONE')` // capture group = group(1)

```
searchText = "ONE TWO THREE"
result = re.search("(ONE)\s(TWO)\s(THREE)", searchText).group(3)
print("match:", result)
```

output: `('match:', 'THREE')` // capture group = group(3)

Notice in the last example I've set up three capture groups (defined in parentheses) and I choose to show output for group(3).

```
searchText = "FOUR TWO THREE"
result = re.search("(ONE)\s(TWO)\s(THREE)", searchText)

if result is not None:
    match = filter(None, result.group(3))
else:
    match = "None"

print("match:", match)
```

To handle the exception `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` you can use an `if` statement to a return a nicer looking response of no match found. Or for no output for none found use:

```
searchText = "ONE TWO THREE"
result = re.search("(ONE)\s(TWO)\s(THREE)", searchText)
print("match:", result)
if result is not None:
    print ("match:", result).group(3)
```

Comment: great, so how do I get around the error:

NoneType: object has no attribute group. Where sometimes group[1] exists and sometimes there is only one aka zero index, or none?

Comment: The error is an indication that there is no match for what you've defined in your pattern group. I've updated my answer with a standard way of handling it.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Is there a way of also saying If there is only one group, I.e. index zero then do something else, and still grab the data?